# Airflow SSH received SIGTERM after warning: Recorded pid 1098 does not match the current pid 31631

Tags: ssh, airflow, paramiko

I'll need a bit of help here.

running airflow on docker container+LocalExecutor.

Airflow version is 2.0.0 (https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/2.0.0/)

I'm running a long runnning task with a wrapper of SSHOperator.
Basically I open an SSH Session to run a spark-submit job in spark edge node.
(YARN JOB succeeds but airflow task fails)

**Task starts with PID 31675:**

```
[2021-06-24 18:29:09,664] {standard_task_runner.py:51} INFO - Started process 31675 to run task
```

Then after sometime getting this warning:

**Recorded pid 1098 does not match the current pid 31631**

And then the tasks fails:

```
[2021-06-24 19:45:44,493] {local_task_job.py:166} WARNING - Recorded pid 1098 does not match the current pid 31631
[2021-06-24 19:45:44,496] {process_utils.py:95} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 31675
[2021-06-24 19:45:44,496] {taskinstance.py:1214} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2021-06-24 19:45:44,528] {taskinstance.py:1396} ERROR - LatamSSH operator error: Task received SIGTERM signal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/latamairflow/operators/latam_ssh_operator.py", line 453, in execute
    readq, _, _ = select([channel], [], [], self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1216, in signal_handler
    raise AirflowException("Task received SIGTERM signal")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task received SIGTERM signal
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1086, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1260, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1300, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/latamairflow/operators/latam_ssh_operator.py", line 502, in execute
    raise AirflowException("LatamSSH operator error: {0}".format(str(e)))
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: LatamSSH operator error: Task received SIGTERM signal
[2021-06-24 19:45:44,529] {taskinstance.py:1440} INFO - Marking task as FAILED.
```

Comment: You might want to try upgrading your Airflow to 2.1.3. There were many bugs in the initial version which may have been resolved in the newer versions. The SIGTERM is handled better based on what it says in this PR - https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16301

Comment: I have exact same case (Airflow SSHOperator used to log into the cluster edge node and run spark-submit), with 2.1.3, as with all versions since 2.0.0, the issue still appears.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Same here, any luck?